# Show function is continuous for all x and y

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

$$ \begin{cases}xy^2\sin\left(\frac 1 y\right), \text {if $y$ $\neq$ 0} \\ 0, \text{if $y$ = 0} \end{cases}$$

I'm not sure how to work out this limit as $x$ goes to infinity. If it were just the y part, I know that $y^2$ goes to 0 and $\sin$ is a limited function, so it has to go to 0, but I don't know what to do with the $x$ term.

The demonstration for the origin is at [Show function is continuous at origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317805/show-function-is-continuous-at-origin)

However, my issue was what happens as y goes to 0 and x to infinity.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you want to know about the behaviour of this function when $x$ and $y$ tend to infinity?

Comment: Why are you posting this again? You have two answers already and you have approved one of the answers.

Comment: The question does not involve $x$ going to infinity, thus the issue is solved.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: It's not a duplicate. The current problem is to show $f$ is continuous on _all_ of $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: Given that you were one of those who voted to close, does an answer to the prior question show that $f$ is continuous at all points of the $x$-axis?

Comment: The answer to this question is identical to the answer to the previous question. If you know the definition of limit then $x \to \infty$ does not arise at all.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: The OP was trying to ask: Is $f$ continuous at $(x,0)$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, not just $x=0$? Look instead at the question title. Also, in the prior question, the OP commented that he meant to ask about the _everywhere_ continuity of $f$. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition you look at continuity at points in domain hence $x$ approaches some constant and not $\infty$ hence we have $xy^2\sin(\frac1 y) \to 0$ as $y\to 0$ paired with the fact that composition and product of continuous functions is continuous you get that the function is continuous.

Comment: So that means that in multivariable calculus it doesn't make sense to ask for the limit of a function where one variable goes to infinity and the other doesn't?